# React Native assetPath.replaceAll() is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo

I keep getting this error. My app has been working perfectly for days but I was having some trouble with env files so I did a complete reinstall and cleaned my cache. Now whenever I try to build the app I get this error:

```
src\images\avatar.jpg: assetUrlPath.replaceAll is not a function
```

This isn't just happening with images either, I also ran into this error with my fonts:

```
node_modules\@expo-google-fonts\montserrat\Montserrat_400Regular.ttf: assetUrlPath.replaceAll is not a function
```

I have removed node_modules, deleted the package-lock.json, cleared my cache again, reinstalled, reinstalled expo, and nothing.

What's more when you put the error into google you get zero results for react-native. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

Answering this just in case someone runs across this error. I am using nvm and forgot that my node version was set to 14. Setting to 18 fixed the issue.